# Add 2 seconds of blank/black video with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4

Let’s say I have two videos I want play simultaneously. movieA.mp4 is 38.6 seconds duration, and movieB.mp4 is 31.14 seconds duration. Using ffmpeg is there an easy way to fill the end of movieB.mp4 with black silence so that it is exactly 38.6 seconds (matching movieA.mp4). There’s a very niche technical reason I want to do this, so don’t ask haha!!

Also if possible, but less important, a way to remove this afterwards.

Been searching for 2 days for any sort of easy way around this without luck!!!

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this via a command like this:

```
ffmpeg -i movieA.mp4 -i movieB.mp4 -filter_complex "color=black:WxH[c]; \
       [0][c]overlay=shortest=1[base];[base][1]overlay=eof_action=pass[v]" \
       -map "[v]" -map 1:a Bextended.mp4
```

This assumes the resolution of the two videos is the same. You should scale them, otherwise, to make it so.

`WxH` should be replaced with the resolution of movieA e.g. `color=black:1280x720`

Comment: Thank you!  Is there an easy way to extend the length of the video with blank/black without a second video?

Comment: Use `"[c][0]overlay=eof_action=pass" -t N` where N is the total length of the extended video. Or you can set duration of color: `"color=black:WxH:d=M[c];[0][c]concat"` skipping the `-t N`. M here is the duration of just the extension.